# Adding a UIImageView to UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton, sdwebimage

I created a UIScrollView which contains several UIImageView instances. The SDWebImage framework is used in order to cache images and present them in the UIImageView instances. Now I want to be able to click on these instances of UIImageView.

Previously I added UIButtons to the UIScrollView and added an image to this button. But know I am not able to add a UIImageView to a button. How should I solve this? is it an option to place an UIButton over this view? and how should I do this?

I previously used this to add clickable images (I need to change this, due to the SDWebImage framework, so I cannot use UIImage imageNamed:forState

```
        CGFloat y = i * self.view.frame.size.height/6; 
        UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [aButton setTag:[[idsCol objectAtIndex: i] intValue]];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.size.width/3, self.view.frame.size.height/6);

        aButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        aButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
        [scrollView addSubview:aButton];
```

I currently need to make the following imageview clickable:

```
[testImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: SDWebImage also has a category for UIButtons - I just use this instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `SDWebImage`, but if this framework would allow you to modify the buttons imageView property directly you'd be better off:

```
[myButton.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with using a image view, you can make it "clickable" by adding a simple tap gesture to it:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[testImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[testImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];




- (void)myMethod:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%u",sender.view.tag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I first tried modify the imageView property as suggested. Unfortunately this did not work! I tried the second one and created a tap recognizer (with the code above). The imageview does handle a tap, but the action is sent to the selector buttonClicked:. This action used to look at the tag of the clicked button. (I used to set [buttonName setTag:tagId]) but I cannot add a tag to the gesture recognizer. any idea what I can do?

Comment: @AlexvanRijs see the changes I made to my post. And forgive any slight mistakes, I'm writing from an iPad.